# RPSLS: How can the program print out the winning logic depending on which player wins?

Tags: python

So in an attempt to learn Python, I am building an RPSLS game for class. I have most of it done (albeit the efficiency can be improved) but want to make the result change depending on what the action is that leads to a win.

For example if Player 1 chose `Spock` and Player 2 chose `Rock`. I want the program to output `Spock vaporizes rock`

I have tested with a 2D array and tried playing around with index, but alas. Any nudge or what to even search for would be appreciated.

This is what my program looks like:

```
winningPairs = [("scissors","paper"),
                ("scissors","lizard"),
                ("spock","scissors"),
                ("spock","rock"),
                ("lizard","spock"),
                ("lizard","paper"),
                ("rock","lizard"),
                ("rock","scissors"),
                ("paper","rock"),
                ("paper","spock")]

actionPairs = [ "  - Scissors cuts paper",
                "  - Scissors decapitates lizard",
                "  - Spock smashes scissors",
                "  - Spock vaporizes rock",
                "  - Lizard poisons Spock",
                "  - Lizard eats paper",
                "  - Rock crushes lizard",
                "  - Rock crushes scissors",
                "  - Paper covers rock",
                "  - Paper disproves Spock"]

# ask players for their name
print()
namePlayerOne = input("Player 1, enter your name: ")
namePlayerTwo = input("Player 2, enter your name: ")
print()

# set two variables for keeping score
playerOneScore = 0
playerTwoScore = 0

# ask if players want to see instructions for winning
instructions = input("Would you like to see instructions for winning (y/n)?")
if instructions == "y":
    for action in actionPairs:
        print(action)
print()

while True:
    # asking players for their choice
    playerOneOption = input(f"{namePlayerOne} select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): ").lower()
    playerTwoOption = input(f"{namePlayerTwo} select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): ").lower() 

    # if both players select the same option, it's always a draw
    if playerOneOption == playerTwoOption: 
        results = "Draw"

    # check if order of input is same as element in winningPairs, if it is Player one wins (who selects first)
    elif (playerOneOption,playerTwoOption) in winningPairs: 
        results = f"{namePlayerOne} wins" # print win
        playerOneScore += 1 # add 1 score to player
        
    # if elif is not true, player two wins
    else:
        results = f"{namePlayerTwo} wins" # print win
        playerTwoScore += 1 # add 1 score to player

    print("-"*20)
    print(f"{namePlayerOne} chose {playerOneOption}\n{namePlayerTwo} chose {playerTwoOption}") # print each player's pick
    print(results) # print results
    print()
    print(f"{namePlayerOne} score: {playerOneScore}\n{namePlayerTwo} score: {playerTwoScore}") # print player scores
    print("-"*20)
    '''for result in actionPairs:
        if (playerOneOption,playerTwoOption) in winningPairs:
            print(result[winningPairs])'''

    playAgain = input("Play again? (y/n): ") # ask if players want to play again
    if playAgain.lower() != "y":
        break
```

This is the output so far, when players do not wish to see instructions:

```
Player 1, enter your name: name1
Player 2, enter your name: name2

Would you like to see instructions for winning (y/n)?n

name1 select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): Rock
name2 select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): Spock
--------------------
name1 chose rock    
name2 chose spock   
name2 wins

name1 score: 0      
name2 score: 1      
--------------------
Play again? (y/n): n
```

before name2 wins I'd like it to say `Spock vaporizes rock, name2 wins` and if the winning conditions were changed, so Player 1 was the winner, it should change it in favor of that player.

Comment: check out my answer if there is any query please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Changes made:-**

```
(1) actionPairs initialised as dictionary
(2) see the edit made portion.
(3) change in the results
```

**Code:-**

```
winningPairs = [("scissors","paper"),
                ("scissors","lizard"),
                ("spock","scissors"),
                ("spock","rock"),
                ("lizard","spock"),
                ("lizard","paper"),
                ("rock","lizard"),
                ("rock","scissors"),
                ("paper","rock"),
                ("paper","spock")]

actionPairs = { 0:"Scissors cuts paper",
                1:"Scissors decapitates lizard",
                2:"Spock smashes scissors",
                3:"Spock vaporizes rock",
                4:"Lizard poisons Spock",
                5:"Lizard eats paper",
                6:"Rock crushes lizard",
                7:"Rock crushes scissors",
                8:"Paper covers rock",
                9:"Paper disproves Spock"}

# ask players for their name
print()
namePlayerOne = input("Player 1, enter your name: ")
namePlayerTwo = input("Player 2, enter your name: ")
print()

# set two variables for keeping score
playerOneScore = 0
playerTwoScore = 0

# ask if players want to see instructions for winning
instructions = input("Would you like to see instructions for winning (y/n)?")
if instructions == "y":
    for action in actionPairs:
        print(action)
print()

while True:
    # asking players for their choice
    playerOneOption = input(f"{namePlayerOne} select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): ").lower()
    playerTwoOption = input(f"{namePlayerTwo} select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): ").lower() 

    #edit made..
    for i in range(len(winningPairs)):
        if winningPairs[i]==(playerOneOption,playerTwoOption) or winningPairs[i]==(playerTwoOption,playerOneOption):
            temp=i
    
    
    # if both players select the same option, it's always a draw
    if playerOneOption == playerTwoOption: 
        results = "Draw"

    
    # check if order of input is same as element in winningPairs, if it is Player one wins (who selects first)
    elif (playerOneOption,playerTwoOption) in winningPairs: 
        results=actionPairs.get(temp,"")+", "
        results += f"{namePlayerOne} wins" # print win
        playerOneScore += 1 # add 1 score to player
        
    # if elif is not true, player two wins
    else:
        results=actionPairs.get(temp,"")+", "
        results += f"{namePlayerTwo} wins" # print win
        playerTwoScore += 1 # add 1 score to player

    print("-"*20)
    print(f"{namePlayerOne} chose {playerOneOption}\n{namePlayerTwo} chose {playerTwoOption}") # print each player's pick
    print(results) # print results
    print()
    print(f"{namePlayerOne} score: {playerOneScore}\n{namePlayerTwo} score: {playerTwoScore}") # print player scores
    print("-"*20)
    '''for result in actionPairs:
        if (playerOneOption,playerTwoOption) in winningPairs:
            print(result[winningPairs])'''

    playAgain = input("Play again? (y/n): ") # ask if players want to play again
    if playAgain.lower() != "y":
        break
```

**Output:-**

```
Player 1, enter your name: Yash
Player 2, enter your name: Rohan
Would you like to see instructions for winning (y/n)?n
Yash select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): rock
Rohan select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): paper
--------------------
Yash chose rock
Rohan chose paper
Paper covers rock, Rohan wins

Yash score: 0
Rohan score: 1
--------------------
Play again? (y/n): y
Yash select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): paper
Rohan select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): rock
--------------------
Yash chose paper
Rohan chose rock
Paper covers rock, Yash wins

Yash score: 1
Rohan score: 1
--------------------
Play again? (y/n): y
Yash select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): paper
Rohan select your option (Rock, Paper, Scissors, Lizard, Spock): paper
--------------------
Yash chose paper
Rohan chose paper
Draw

Yash score: 1
Rohan score: 1
--------------------
Play again? (y/n): n
```